# Usr home is not exist

Tags: session

I am using centos os. I could not activated some wordpress plugin becuause of **session.save_path** error.

on /usr/ directory these folders exist;

> bin  games    kerberos  lib64    local  share  tmp etc  include  lib
>   libexec  sbin   src

But I must add this;

> ini_set("upload_tmp_dir", "/usr/home/user-name/tmp/");

to **wp-blog-header.php** file.

Answer (score 1):

> ini_set("upload_tmp_dir", "/usr/home/user-name/tmp/");

What this does is set which directory PHP uses for temporary storage of uploads.

If /usr/home/user-name/tmp/ doesn't exist, specify a directory that DOES exist to use as the upload temp directory.

[More info about upload_tmp_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)